# Is a noble permanently yours once he's visited you in Splendor?

Tags: splendor

[Splendor](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/148228/splendor) is a great game, but the [rules](http://www.spacecowboys.fr/img/games/splendor/details/rules/Rules_Splendor_US.pdf) were written sub-optimally.

> At the end of their turn, each player checks the noble tiles in order to determine if they’re receiving a visit from one of them.

Do you check the nobles currently "visiting" another player, or is a noble permanently yours once he's visited you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two people from [Splendor](http://us.asmodee.com/ressources/jeux_versions/splendor.php)-distributor Asmodee have confirmed<sup>[[1]](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/15928679#15928679)[[2]](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/15939999#15939999)</sup> that you retain any noble that has visited you.